# verilog code for octal to binary

Tags: verilog

```
module hgf(oct,bin);
input [1:0]oct;
output [7:0]bin;
reg[1:0]n;
reg [7:0]k;
integer i,d;
always@(*)
begin
n = oct;
while(n<0)
begin
d=(d+(n%10))* (8^i);
n=n/10;
end
i=1;
while(d!=0)
begin
k = k+(d%2)*i;
d=d/2;
i=i*10;
end

end
assign bin=k;
endmodule
```

I tried the above code for to convert octal to binary, but it has some error. It seems like C coding. Yeah I got C code and I converted it into verilog based on my knowledge.

I am the beginner of verilog. Please, anybody help me.

Comment: It is not correct.

Comment: the code above is incorrect even in 'c'. And even in 'c' it is advisable to indent your code and make it readable.  Besides, what was the error and what was the purpose of it? in both 'c' and 'verilog' '%o' provides formatted output in octal form.

Answer (score 0):

You have no octal numbers in there. They come in units of three bits. You have something you call octal but it has only two bits.

Here is an image of an old PDP11 with an 18 bit entry panel consisting of six octal numbers. I am showing this to give you a hint on how to take multiple octal numbers and convert them into a larger binary number. In Verilog you would not use a module for that as *it takes only a single statement to accomplish*.

[image]

You code would not have worked anyway as default all numbers in Verilog are unsigned. So "while(n<0)" does not work.